# How do I ask for new features in Ubuntu?

Tags: community

I would like to know how to ask for new features in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please give an example of feature. That would make the question more clear.

Answer (score 15):

Visit the [Ubuntu Wishlist](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/Wishlist) Wiki or [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) and suggest away!!

Answer (score 0):

You can share your ideas and featre at https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel-discuss